# Shallow link not working with middleware in the root

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

**Shallow** option doesn't work with middleware in the root of my project, `./src/middleware.ts`

The link in the browser is changing but not updating the pages.

I used NextLink in the sidebar to navigate between pages, like:

```
<NextLink href='/dashboard' passHref shallow>Dashboard</NextLink>
<NextLink href='/users' passHref shallow>Users</NextLink>
<NextLink href='/users' passHref shallow>Posts</NextLink>
```

Also, I'm trying as a `router.push` with shallow on elements to navigate,like button or div:

```
<Button onClick={() => router.push('/dashboard', {}, { shallow: true })}>Dashboard</Button>
```

```
import { NextResponse, NextMiddleware } from 'next/server';

const PUBLIC_FILE = /\.(.*)$/;
export const middleware: NextMiddleware = (req) => {
  const acceptLanguage =
    req?.headers?.get('accept-language') &&
    req?.headers?.get('accept-language')?.slice(0, 2);

  if (
    req.nextUrl.pathname.startsWith('/_next') ||
    req.nextUrl.pathname.includes('/api/') ||
    PUBLIC_FILE.test(req.nextUrl.pathname)
  ) {
    return;
  }

  if (req.nextUrl.locale === 'default') {
    const newUrl = req.nextUrl.clone();
    
    newUrl.locale = acceptLanguage || 'en';
    
    return NextResponse.redirect(newUrl);
  }
};


"next": "^12.3.4",
"next-translate": "^2.0.4",
"react": "^17.0.2",
"react-dom": "^17.0.2"
```

Comment: On which page do you have that `Button` and `NextLink`? What are you expecting? How it's not working? Please elaborate more so we have a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: The link is changing, but the page does not load. I should press reload to load the page

Comment: Are you getting a white screen? Any errors in the consoles?

Comment: No errors. I stay on the current page when I click on another link. but the link in the browser changes. If I remove shallow then the page can load. Or with shallow but removed the middleware

Comment: I'm not sure how I can test this. In an early version of nextjs, when the middleware was in src/page/_middleware.ts, the shallow always works

Answer (score 0):

A shallow routing is not meant to be used for navigation between pages. It's only to update the path of your current page, on the client, for example, to update query parameters, as they say on the [documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/shallow-routing):

> Shallow routing allows you to change the URL without running data fetching methods again, that includes `getServerSideProps`, `getStaticProps`, and `getInitialProps`.

> You'll receive the updated `pathname` and the `query` via the `router` object (added by `useRouter` or `withRouter`), without losing state.

If you use it as you did without a middleware involved, you get the [below behavior](https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/shallow-routing#caveats),  like `shallow` wasn't set:

> Shallow routing only works for URL changes in the current page. For example, let's assume we have another page called `pages/about.js`, and you run this:

```
router.push('/?counter=10', '/about?counter=10', { shallow: true })
```

> Since that's a new page, it'll unload the current page, load the new one and wait for data fetching even though we asked to do shallow routing.

And it won't work well when a middleware is involved, as they specifically say on [documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/shallow-routing#caveats):

> When shallow routing is used with middleware it will not ensure the new page matches the current page like previously done without middleware. This is due to middleware being able to rewrite dynamically and can't be verified client-side without a data fetch which is skipped with shallow, so a shallow route change must always be treated as shallow.